# Why is assignment to a list of variables inconsistent?

Tags: raku

To save 2 values from a list returned by a sub and throw the third away, one can;

```
(my $first, my $second) = (1, 2, 3);
print $first, "\n";
print $second, "\n";
exit 0;
```

and it works as expected (in both perl5 and perl6).  If you want just the first however;

```
(my $first) = (1, 2, 3);
print $first, "\n";
exit 0;
```

... you get the whole list.  This seems counter-intuitive - why the inconsistency?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be due to the [single argument rule](https://design.perl6.org/S07.html#The_single_argument_rule). You get the expected behaviour by adding a trailing `,`:

```
(my $first,) = (1, 2, 3);
```

Note that while this works as declarations return containers, which are first-class objects that can be put in lists, you're nevertheless doing it 'wrong':

The assignments should read

```
my ($first, $second) = (1, 2, 3);
```

and

```
my ($first) = (1, 2, 3);
```

Also note that the parens on the right-hand side are superfluous as well (it's the comma that does list construction); the more idiomatic versions would be

```
my ($first, $second) = 1, 2, 3;
```

and

```
my ($first) = 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: I don't quite get why `my ($first) = 1,2,3`; *does* work as intended.  Shouldn't the single argument apply there as well?  In other words, how is this different from `(my $first) = 1,2,3;` or `my $first; ($first) = 1,2,3;`?

Comment: @mscha: parens are syntactically overloaded: they are used as part of declaration syntax as well as to delimit ordinary lists (that may happen to contain things that are assignable); syntactically it might look similar, but semantically, apples and oranges

Comment: @mscha: for consistency's sake, it might have been a good idea to make th rules the same, but note that list sematics evolved during the rather lengthy development process of Perl6

Answer (score 6):

```
(my $first, ) = (1,2,3);
dd $first; # OUTPUT«Int $first = 1␤»
```

In your first example you assign a list (or a part thereof) to a list of containers. Your second example does exactly what you ask it for. A list of values is assigned to one container. In Perl 5, the list is constructed by the parentheses (in this case), whereby in Perl 6 the list is constructed by the comma. The latter is used in my example to get what is asked for.

I would argue that it's Perl 5 that is inconsistent as sometimes lists are constructed by commas, parentheses or brackets.

```
my ($first,$,$third) = (1,2,3);
dd $first, $third; # OUTPUT«Int $first = 1␤Int $third = 3␤»
```

You can skip one or many list elements by adding anonymous state variables. This also leads to a shortcut to your first example.

```
my $first,$ = 1,2,3;
dd $first; # OUTPUT«Any $first = Any␤»
```